# Visual Studio ReportViewer - Change many matrix colum widths at once

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, matrix, reporting

I was wondering if it was possible to change many column widths in a matrix all at once instead of selecting each one and typing the correct width. Is there a way to change it once, then  select the other cells and press ctrl-y or shift-alt-backspcace (redo)? I have over 150 columns to change manually every time the report is modified.
The redo options seems to be disabled for matrix operations, such as adding columns/rows and formatting cells.

Furthermore, can anyone tell me why merging columns outside the double dotted line (default column group?) will cause trailing empty columns to be resized?

Thanks!